# postgres php exception handling

Tags: php, postgresql, exception, pdo

I have seen this question asked before on SO, and none of the answers seem to be complete. So please...

I have code using PDO and PDOStatement. It was originally written to work without exceptions, and I'm converting it to work with.

My simple questions are:

1. Are there any circumstances in which it is useful or necessary to continue to check the return value of functions for FALSE ( when this means "failure" ), or can I simply execute the method and assume that all kinds of failure will trigger an exception? I saw an example in an answer where someone was recommended to use BOTH try-catch AND to test the return value for FALSE - which, it is IS actually necessary, makes for some very ugly code.
2. Is there a proper list of which methods may, and which can never, throw an exception? I have seen answers which say "if you find we haven't documented an exception we throw, raise a bug", but that's not altogether helpful. I have seen statements that "the manual page says when an exception can be thrown", but the PDO::query and PDOStatement::execute pages make no mention of exceptions - which surely can't be true ... can it? Essentially I'd like to know whether prepare, bind[things], fetch[all], execute and a few others may or will never, throw stuff.

I don't feel I'm asking the earth, and if I have to I could look at the code, but surely the manual documentation on this should be rock solid.

[edit to add an example]

I now find myself with code blocks like this - I would like to simplify it by removing the test of the return value, but I cannot convince myself that it is correct. Other blocks use execute() and so on.

```
try {
  /* I do not know whether beginTransaction throws an exception when it would otherwise return FALSE.
   * If it does then checking the return value is spurious, and the code cam be simplified.
   */
  if (FALSE == $customerDb->beginTransaction()) {
    Log::add("Database begin transaction failed.",
              Log::ERROR);
  throw new Exception("Failed to begin a transaction.");
  }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  /* The documentation does not mention the possibility of
   *  beginTransaction() throwing any exception,
   *  even when we have configured all the other functions to do so.
   */
  Log::add("Database begin transaction threw an exception: " . $e->getMessage(),
           Log::ERROR);
  throw new Exception("Begin transaction threw an exception.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is three error handling strategies, `ERRMODE_SILENT` (the default one), `ERRMODE_WARNING` and  `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Only the last one make PDO throw exceptions if errors occurs, so except if you tell PDO explicitly to run in exception mode with:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

It will not throw any exception except for `PDO:__construct()` which will throw an exception if the connection fails, whatever the value of `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`.

From the doc:

> `PDO::__construct()` will always throw a `PDOException` if the connection
>   fails regardless of which `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` is currently set. Uncaught
>   Exceptions are fatal.

I suggest you to read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) - it's pretty clear how PDO handle errors.

#### Update

In your code sample, the exception will never be catched as you typed your catch block exception to `PDO_Exception` and you're throwing an `Exception` - which is the lower exception type level. If you want to catch all exceptions type, cast your catch parameter to `Exception` - currently your catch block capture only `PDOException`.

That being said, let's focus on the confusion you have about exceptions. There is **no mysterious** exceptions being thrown when in `ERRMODE_SILENT` or `ERRMODE_WARNING`, except the one from the PDO controller - which is documented. People telling otherwise are probably working in a PDO environment they don't really know / control - like a framework who use PDO but throw its own exceptions for queries, or changing the `ATTR_ERRMODE` in specific cases. I suggest you to focus less on the discussion under docs (as sometimes there could be interesting stuffs in it, most of the time it's comments from confused people) and focus more on the docs itself.

Let's be clear about what happen with errors in PDO.

1. An error occurs. If it happens in the PDO controller, an exception will be thrown and all next steps will be ignored.
2. The error will be standardized according to [the SQL-92 standard](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jenut/ch08_06.htm) (see this link for all the return codes that exists). From the doc :

   > PDO standardizes on using SQL-92 SQLSTATE error code strings; individual PDO drivers are responsible for mapping their native codes to the appropriate SQLSTATE codes.
3. PDO check for the `ATTR_ERMODE` attribute to know how it should handle this error.

   1. `ERRMODE_SILENT` (the default mode)

      The error will not be reported, so you'll need to check for the return of the PDO functions for `false` and check the  [`PDO::errorCode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php), [`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) or [`PDOStatement::errorCode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php), [`PDOStatement::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) depending of the object you're using to get the error details.
   2. `ERRMODE_WARNING`

      Same as `ERRMODE_SILENT` but an `E_WARNING` PHP error will be thrown. Could be usefull for developpment, but you still need to check the function returns for `false`.
   3. `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

      A `PDO_Exception` will be thrown. There will be **no need** to check the function return for `false` as when an exception is thrown, the next lines will be skipped and PHP will go to the catch block, or if there is not any catch block it will throw a PHP error. So implementation you suggest is redundant when running in `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

So yes, the doc doesn't said that x function throw an exception because it will be totally redundant. The error handling page explain everything you need to know.

If you're still not convinced, I suggest to try it by yourself: play with `ATTR_ERRMODE` and some various PDO functions, and see by yourself.

Comment: vard.
Thank you for your reply, all of which I knew, but it doesn't seem to help.
It seems to have little or nothing to do with my 2 questions.
I have read "the docs", and if they covered it I would not have asked the question.
The docs are UNCLEAR, viz 2 examples ( query and execute ) where exceptions are surely thrown but I see nothing in the docs.
"pretty clear" is not "actually clear".
If you follow your link you will see a comment by Praveen Raj, which pretty much echoes the enquiry/complaint I'm making here! And it has been asked, but not answered, a number of times before on SO.

Comment: I still don't get what you don't understand here. `PDO::query` doesn't throw any exception if you're not in exception mode, same as `PDO::statement:execute`. And about Praveen comment, he's just saying that if you set `ATTR_ERRMODE` to `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, it will apply to `PDOStatement` object too. All of the methods he's quoting are clearly documented, ex for `prepare`: "PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).". I don't see how it could be more clear than that.

Comment: And you misreading the doc, when they say "if you find we haven't documented an exception we throw, raise a bug", it's about the **exception** itself doc, not the fact the exception is raised by the function - this is documentated.

Comment: OK. We're clearly not seeing the same thing. Consider http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
I see one mention of an error under discussion of input parameters.
I see no documentation of exceptions.
I see no statement that (when enabled) an exception will always be thrown instead of returning "FALSE", so if you enable exceptions you need never test the return value for FALSE. 
That discussion may exist elsewhere, but I haven't found it.

Comment: I have appended a code sample showing my confusion to the question.

Comment: I updated my answer to give some more explanations. I hope it will clear the confusion.

Comment: vard - thank you for the assertive amendment, which makes me happier. I can see how you feel that "there is no need to document exceptions on each function page, as it is implicit that things which would return FALSE to flag failure will always throw an exception instead". It's obviously the desirable behaviour, but I am not the only one who has come along asking for a clear statement. It would be easier to just amend the "Return Values" section of each page to say "returns FALSE, or throws an exception when selected". Especially since fetch() behaves differently and can always return FALSE.